# how to download a file from server?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

i have successfully uploaded multiple file to server  using  apache common-fileupload and common-io.Uploaded location is  a direcory on the server for eg it may be c:\uploaded

Now how to download a file from server ? specifically from directory on the server

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to do it from your servlet. Something like this code should do the trick:

```
  public void sendFile(HttpServletResponse response, File file)
         throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
      is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

      while (int val = fis.read() >= 0) {
        response.getOutputStream().write(val);
      }
    } finally {
      if( is != null ) {
        is.close();
      }
    }
  }
```

Assuming, of course, you've set the `content-type` header and so on previously. There's room for optimisation, but it's the general idea.